# Supported AMD cards on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: amd-graphics

I'm on Ubuntu 16.10 and I'm planning to upgrade to 17.04.  I've read a few things about bugs with AMD cards not fully supported.  I just want to be sure it's safe for me to upgrade.  I have a AMD Radeon HD 6450 ddr3 1gb (Caicos).  Is it supported on 17.04?  If yes, what should I do before I upgrade?

*Am I right, by reading this, to think that my card is supported?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Comment: It looks like it should be, but that's isn't a guarantee, but the 6450 has a good history of being compatible by the looks of that page. If you do plan to upgrade to 17.04 I would get a good back up before the upgrade in case you need to revert for one reason or another. Another issue is that I can't find a lot of information about the 6450 and 17.04, which could mean one of two things, either it's easy or nobody has done it yet. Good luck either way. If you do take the plunge and find it works, you can write up your answer for those that follow.

Comment: Did you test the life version (start ubuntu 17.04 without installing it just to make sure)?

Comment: I'm doing a backup of my system each day already so that's ok.  I tought of doing a test with a live version like a year ago...thanks for the reminder!  *Sorry for these updates of my post...I'm on a bus trying to write it quickly...

Comment: I will do an update here as soon as I can.